# Term for vote cartels

Tags: discussion, voting, sock-puppets

What's a widely used term for a (small) group of users voting up each other's questions / answers/ comments?

Does Stack Overflow have any tools/rules in place to prevent this? Say for instance maximum amount of rep from one user to another? I've seen the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), and it only discusses per day maximums.

I did do a search as my assumption is that this would've been discussed before - but I can't think of a search term other than 'cartel', which yields no results.

Just curious.

Comment: Try "voting ring", that may turn up some hits.

Comment: Have you found one, or are you part of one?

Comment: If you have a hunch that you've discovered a voting ring, flag a post by one of the participants for moderation attention and explain that you suspect sockpuppetry. It'd be helpful to provide links to the other users' profiles.

Comment: @slugster - my ring's clearly not very effective !! 'voting ring' turns up just this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116699/does-the-sharing-an-answer-encourage-ring-voting

Comment: @yannis - really just curious. I've no suspicion / evidence of a voting ring.

Comment: Some of the rings we find are certainly elaborate enough to earn being called cartels. :)

Comment: @slugster he doesn't seems to be a part of it. I have experience of finding such things, so i can say that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's called a voting ring, and it's considered abusive behaviour. If it's only two / three accounts, we may also call them [sockpuppets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_%28Internet%29).

Moderators have a few tools to detect unusual voting patterns, and that includes groups of people voting each other en masse. If a voting ring is discovered, the usual route is to invalidate the group's votes and suspend everyone involved. I think this is as much information as I can give you on the subject, the rest is super secret.

Voting ring and sockpuppetry are not specific to Stack Exchange / Overflow, they are widely used terms in online communities that have some form of voting, like Hacker News, Reddit, Digg, Quora etc.

Comment: Is it true the algorithms exploit a vulnerability in certain Netgear routers that makes the device overheat, and burns down the perpetrator's house?

Comment: @Discount Gucci Handbags: We can neither confirm nor deny this.

Comment: Ah, I always figured that sockpuppets are really just one single person, (ab)using multiple accounts?

Comment: @Arjan Mostly that, but we also use the term when it's people knowing each other in real life. Some times it's completely innocent, a friend thinking he's doing another friend a favour.

Comment: The algo at work: http://dailypicksandflicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Evil-cows-old-mcdonald-had-a-farm-had.jpg

Comment: The term you are looking for is 'meatpuppet'.

Comment: I call this phenomenon a ``cross-pollination``.

Comment: Technically, doesn't the entirety of StackExchange constitute this?