# Reopen votes against closed votes which are not explained

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

This question is related to my previous question about [Close votes based on opinion which cannot be explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229721/votes-based-on-opinion-or-just-feeling-is-allowed-in-stack-exchange), except this question is about reopen votes instead.

Can I vote to reopen based on the following reasons?

- I feel it is answerable, clear or understandable.
- The question was closed unfairly; the close voters had not explained their rationale clearly.

Comment: What do you mean "unfairly"?

Comment: @random, Unfair means Close voters didn't follow the similar flow chart(which is shown by shog9 as answer) to close a question. And they didn't think hardly to close.

Comment: BVR, you are misusing the word 'unfair'.  Unfair means 'not based on or behaving according to the principles of equality and justice.'  Your question was closed fully within the rules.  You mean "I disagree with the question being closed", which you're free to do.

Comment: @Joe, if that is true why closed voters unable to explain  rationale?

Comment: Who says they are, @BVR?

Comment: Unable to explain, or don't want to / haven't taken the time to explain? IMHO there's a lot of speculation on your side about how and why people are voting to close (your) questions.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, the questions I have asked couldnot answered by closed voters

Comment: @yuck, what is IMHO?

Comment: That's a good reason why it should have been closed...

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, why close voters unable to explain when I have probed the reasons?

Comment: What? Not only was the close reason explained in the blurb following the close reason, two of the close voters explained their reasoning in the comments. You may not agree with their reasons, but there it is. It really seems like you're willfully ignoring them, and coming here to whinge.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, Do you think I don't have any job to do other than whinge? I hate these baseless opinions and actions.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, Bob saying unclear. No body explained why it is unclear.Antp put comments which I have asked for clarifications. But Antp didn't provide clarification except saying what he feels

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, Jonesy not even bother to clarify question that I have asked in the comment

Comment: Well, stated differently: the users who voted to close are under absolutely no obligation to explain themselves. The lack of an explanation is not a cause for any exceptional action around reopening (you are free to vote to reopen yourself, of course, if you have the rep). You may not agree with the reasoning provided by the close-voters, but... well, that's it. The voters did not act maliciously, or in violation of the rules here. Life moves on.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta,  well. At the end of the day, they don't have obligation. I(some other user) don't understand or agree with close reason. In that case can I vote for reopen or not that is the subject of discussion here

Comment: I don't know. Can you? Serious question. You don't have the reputation to vote to reopen questions by other users (that's 3K). I don't know if you can vote to reopen your own question regardless of rep, but I think you can. Try it!

Answer (score 14):

Reopening is hard. It requires thinking, which is also hard. Fortunately, I have done some of the hard thinking for you, and made [a handy flow-chart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216755/reopen-minimal-understanding-questions/216761#216761) for your benefit:

### Should I re-open a closed question?

[image: a flowchart]

Note that this also doubles as a handy Stack Exchange drinking game.

Comment: I'd be drunk in 5 clicks. It'd be like, 'Name that drunk."

Comment: So, I have to make a decision **before** having a beer?

Comment: Decisions are always easier after a beer. Or three.

Comment: NOW YOU KNOW, @Asad. AND KNOWING IS HALF THE BATTLE! (The other half is managing to type a coherent flag message after a few beers)

Comment: @Shog9, Thanks for answer. But my question is can I reopen based on the stated reasons? What if I don't follow the flow chart and vote reopen just because of the  specified reasons in my question?

Comment: You *can* do whatever you want, @BVR. Whether you *should* or not is another matter. This is my guidance - read it, then make your own decisions.

Comment: @Shog9, If I don't follow your flow chart is there any punishment like suspension or deletion of my account?

Comment: That *really* depends on how far you deviate, @BVR. If, for instance, you replace "Go have a beer" with "post lots of spam" then that would tend to change the outcome considerably.

Comment: @Shog9, I am against closing a question without proper rationale or proper reason. I believe Close voters also think hard to close question and should be able to explain the rationale behind close vote.

Comment: I'm against re-opening crap questions for bureaucratic reasons, @BVR.

Comment: @Shog9, if close voters doesn't explain the reason, if I vote for reopen, does my action categorized as deviated?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/725/discussion-between-bvr-and-shog9)

Comment: For those for whom Alcohol is not an acceptable end-point - do what I do and "keep calm and have a fresh cup of Tea"... 8-) ⊇