# What happened to my account? What am I suspended for?

Tags: support, voting, account-suspension

Yesterday, when I wanted to log back into my [politics.stackexchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour) account for a long time, everything was the same as with the new registration and all the progress I had there until now is gone. Also, when I go into my account, I see the following

> This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The
> suspension period ends on Jul 10, 2024 at 15:41.

I hope this is the right place for such a question.

Here are some of my previous achievements.

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to browse from a shared internet, e.g. coffee shop, library, school, etc.?

Comment: My understanding is that the "voting irregularities" suspension reason is usually given for using sock puppets, participating in voting rings, or otherwise trying to cheat the voting system. Were you doing one of those things?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I'm 100% sure there was never anyone who stood up and admitted such a thing. But, since the OP also refuse to answer less trivial questions, it's fishy enough to end the benefit of the doubt I gave them. This is not innocent question.

Comment: What do you mean by "progress I had there"? You have no questions or answers.

Comment: .... nor any approved edits. The only "progress" that I can see is an "informed" badge.

Comment: @EJoshuaS What are voting rings?

Comment: @plotall Basically it's a group of people that repeatedly vote up each other's content without regard to its quality. It's considered a form of voting fraud because it's an effort to manipulate the voting system (which is why they give suspensions for it). See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137448/term-for-vote-cartels). On the other hand, a sock puppet is a second account that you control. If you have one use it to vote up your content, that's also considered fraud because it doesn't reflect anyone's independent assessment of the quality of the post.

Comment: @plotall Did you use a second account to vote for your content, or did you have other people you know where you would repeatedly vote for each other's content? (If so, that was probably the basis for the suspension because both are seen as efforts to manipulate the reputation system).

Comment: @plotall Also, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373651/what-is-the-purpose-of-voting-rings) is a helpful resource. Again, coordinated upvoting is considered fraudulent, so if you were doing that (or appeared to be doing that) that's probably the reason for the suspension. (In fact, targeting any specific user for upvoting *or* downvoting is not permitted, since votes are supposed to reflect the quality of the content rather than who's posting it).

Comment: @EJoshuaS The link was actually helpful. I don't have a second account, but what exactly does "people you know" mean? Does that mean people that I personally know, or also people that I can glimpse from the net? Maybe that sounds exaggerated, but we talked here for a while, would that count as know?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's what it says. Something was apparently fishy about your voting, and someone investigated and found something that seemed wrong.

Quite a lot of the time moderators escalate it to the community team for investigation and they can see who you've voted for.

Since the maximum period a moderator can suspend you for is a year, you should have been suspended on July 10th this year, and you should have gotten a message in your stack exchange inbox *and* an email letting you know this is the case.

You *should* read that message - you've one opportunity to respond (unless they do) to them.

It'll look something like this (the top one)

[image]

That said, voting fraud is *serious* and moderators tend to make very sure before suspending a user. There *may* be additional investigation and a fair amount of certainty. And we *have* heard people give every excuse under the sun. Mods *can* get it wrong but there's many indicators of an issue that we look at first.

If its not in your inbox and your email, you can use the contact link at the bottom of the page to contact staff to review

Comment: Would the mod message still be available if their account was deleted and recreated, which appears to be the case for OP?

Comment: There's also an email. I've not tested account deletion and recreation so I don't know

Comment: Well, there's also the chance someone sharing the same IP got their account suspended, so when the system identifies new account created from that IP, it auto suspends it. No?

Comment: Nope. That's usually not the case I think.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack No - the system doesn't do that based on IP, it does it based on account ID. Recreating a new site *profile* that has the same network *account* ID will reinstate existing suspensions.

Comment: _"you've one opportunity to respond (unless they do) to them"_ I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the "unless they do" part. Could you please clarify?

Comment: If you respond, then they respond, you can respond back, more or less

Comment: @41686d6564 it means that it's not an open chat, user can't respond to moderator message more than once. (Makes total sense, to prevent abuse and flooding of the mods inbox.)

Comment: So if by message you mean moderator message, I can't access that message.

Comment: I never got an email.